# GLM regression prediction- understanding which factor level is success

Tags: r, regression, prediction, glm

I have built a binomial glm model. The model predicts output between two potential classes: AD or Control. These variables are factors with levels: {AD, Control}. I use this model to predict and obtain probabilities for each sample, but it is unclear to me if a probability over 0.5 indicates AD or Control.

Here is my dataset:

```
> head(example)
          cleaned_mayo$Diagnosis pca_results$x[, 1]
1052_TCX                      AD          0.9613241
1104_TCX                      AD         -0.9327390
742_TCX                       AD          1.6908874
1945_TCX                 Control          0.6819104
134_TCX                       AD          0.5184748
11386_TCX                Control          0.4669661
```

And here is my code to compute the model and make predictions:

```
# Randomize rows of top performer
example<- example[sample(nrow(example)),]

# Subset data for training and testing
N_train<- round(nrow(example)*0.75)
train<- example[1:N_train,]
test<- example[(N_train+1):nrow(example),]
colnames(train)[1:2]<- c("Diagnosis", "Eigen_gene")
colnames(test)[1:2]<- c("Diagnosis", "Eigen_gene")

# Build model and predict   
model_IFGyel<- glm(Diagnosis ~ Eigen_gene, data = train, family = binomial())
pred<- predict(model_IFGyel, newdata= test, type= "response")

# Convert predictions to accuracy metric
pred[which(pred<0.5)]<- "AD"
pred[which(pred!="AD")]<- "Control"
test$Diagnosis<- as.character(test$Diagnosis)
example_acc<- sum(test$Diagnosis==pred, na.rm = T)/nrow(test)
```

Any help clarifying what these prediction probabilities indicate is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `?glm` we note:

> Details:
>
> A typical predictor has the form ‘response ~ terms’ where
>      ‘response’ is the (numeric) response vector and ‘terms’ is a
>      series of terms which specifies a linear predictor for ‘response’.
>      For ‘binomial’ and ‘quasibinomial’ families the response can also
>      be specified as a ‘factor’ (**when the first level denotes failure
>      and all others success**) or as a two-column matrix with the columns
>      giving the numbers of successes and failures.

The key part is highlighted. Assuming you didn't specify the levels (i.e. R's default assignment took place), then `AD` would be failures and `Control` would be successes. Hence the coefficients/model would be in terms of the probability that observation is in the `Control` class.

If you want to change this, use `factor(...., levels = c('Control', 'AD'))` or just do 1 - prob(Control) (1 - predicted value) to get it in terms of `AD`.